# How can I add to a Dojo Grid Event instead of replacing it?

Tags: datagrid, grid, handler, dojo

I have a dojo grid on which I want to perform some action when the "ENTER" key is pressed.  However, I only want to add to what DOJO already does when a key is pressed.  When I try to use a handler it replaces the onKeyDown function in dojox.grid._Events instead of adding to it.  Is there any way I can make sure that the _Events function is called before my additions in my handler function?

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to the onKeyPress function on the grid object.  For example:

```
var grid = dijit.byId('myGrid');
dojo.connect( grid, "onKeyPress", function(evt) {
  if(evt.keyCode === dojo.keys.ENTER) { 
    console.log('ENTER!'); 
  }
});
```

The `dojox.grid._Grid` class (which is a parent class for all grids) is extended from `dojox.grid._Events` so all of those methods are available for connecting.

Comment: I added this in the addOnLoad function and got nothing. dojo.addOnLoad(function() { <your code here> }); Tried both onKeyPress and onKeyDown, tried both console.log and alert. I'm using dojo 1.3 in IE 1.6.

Comment: Is your grid in a div with id = 'myGrid'?  Is the grid object undefined?